# Is there a way to monitor Health Check of an application in Grafana?

Tags: java, prometheus, grafana, smallrye, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I want to monitor the health check of a Java application in Grafana. (the liveness and readiness)
I used smallrye-health.
There is a way to see in Grafana if the app is healthy or not? and Ready or not?
Thanks.

Blackbox exporter can query endpoints like /health/live and /health/ready and it checks the status code, I'am not sure that it can read the json result and display it in Grafana.

Comment: Hi , What features does your app have that you want to monitor? 

api  ?